# How to manage ServiceHost in Windows service from a Winforms admin tool?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, windows-services, wcf-hosting

I have a Windows service that create more than one instance of `ServiceHost`...

I want to be able to manage those `ServiceHosts` through an external winforms admin tool, so I can open and close each of the `ServiceHost` from a UI.

What are my options (apart from wrapping each `ServiceHost` with process)?

Answer (score 0):

You can register one service multiple times with different start parameter and name.
Such configuration could be more robust.

sc.exe create Service_1 binPath= "C:\bin\myserv.exe -run=serviceFirst"  DisplayName = "Server 1"

sc.exe create Service_2 binPath= "C:\bin\myserv.exe -run=serviceSecond" DisplayName = "Server 2"

Answer (score 0):

I would expose another (WCF) service from your (Windows) service, exposing operations to manipulate the service hosts in that process.